# How to select a radio button that changes its id' in selenium?

Tags: java, dynamic, selenium, radio-button, selenium-ide

I need some help trying to select a radio button on Selenium IDE. 
This radio button value changes randomly, due this I cannot get the radio button selected.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways selenium can locate an element other than referencing the id of an element.  Have you also tried using a xpath or css selector?  Take a look at the [selenium docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-elements) for locating an element for examples of using xpath or css selectors.

Post an example of your html and I can help you write the selector.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The html is: <tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>Ok</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//input[@name='encodedcollection_COLLECTION' and @value='1169268']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>

Comment: No prob.  I actually meant the html of the page you're trying to test.  Not the selenium testcase.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

```
storeAttribute| path of area where radiobutton placed @ id| variableName
```

Now you have dynamic id of that element . Use that value to click on it.

```
click| ${variableName}
```

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot get the right path of the area where the radiobutton is placed. This ID changes constantly, and I cannot find the radioButton HTML Xpath to enter the correct path. Just one questions to your answer, in wich part of the Selenium IDE script has the storeAttribute be writen? Would you give me an example? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It will be great if you provide some part of HTML where radio button is located. FYI storeAttribute is command, path of the variable @ID is your target and value as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS or Xpath selector instead of the default used when you recorded your script.

For example, try [this page](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm) with radio button examples, scroll down to the Milk/Butter/Cheese example:

The selector for the first radio button ("Milk") could be one of the following:

```
css = .table5 > input
css = .table5 > input[value='Milk']
```

A couple of ways you could select the second button would be:

```
css = .table5 > input ~ input
css = .table5 > input[value='Butter']
```

You may need to read up on CSS selectors and/or Xpath. You can do a web search for cheat sheets and primers. They are both essential for optimum Selenium scripting, be it with IDE, RC, or Webdriver.

You will find that [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) is also a great tool to help you build your selectors.